# Effective way to memoize a combination of two numbers

Tags: ruby, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm working on an algorithm to count the number of ways to build 100 cents given an infinite amount of pennies, dimes, nickels, and quarters.

I ended up coming with the above (which AFAIK works):

```
def count_ways(amount)
  num_ways(amount, 0)
end

def num_ways(amount, index)
  return 1 if amount == 0
  return 0 if index >= COINS.length || amount < 0
  num_ways(amount - COINS[index], index) +
  num_ways(amount, index + 1)
end
```

Now, I'd like to memoize this algorithm. An effective way I've found to think about memoizing is to consider what inputs do we pass into this function repeatedly. In this case, I'd like to memoize the combination of amount & index parameters.

Typically when I have two parameters, I build a two D array as a way to memoize but here that makes a lot less sense. Consequently, how can you memoize off of these two parameters? Does it make sense to do something like this?

```
def count_ways(amount)
  memo = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
  num_ways(amount, 0, memo)
end

def num_ways(amount, index, memo)
  return 1 if amount == 0
  return 0 if index >= COINS.length || amount < 0
  memo[amount - COINS[index], index] ||= num_ways(amount - COINS[index], index)
  memo[amount, index + 1] ||= num_ways(amount, index + 1)

  memo[amount - COINS[index], index] +
    memo[amount, index + 1]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no common way to implement memoization when you solve algo task. Because of speed. Way you have to choose depends on you algo, input data and so on.
Few imperative rules:

- avoid creation of many data structure instances: `h = {}; h[ [1,2] ] 
  = 3` will produce `COINS.size` * `amount` `Array`s just for keys
- use `Array` for *contiguous* data and `Hash` for *gapped* one
- use `Hash` instead of `Array` when you can't predict data size
- create `Array` with needed values when you can predict your
  *contiguous* data size

Using that rules, memoization (just in your case, where `COINS.size` << `amount` and both datas are *contiguous*) might look like:

```
COINS = [25, 10, 5, 1]

def count_ways(amount)
  # memo is just COINS.size + 1 Array instances
  # a[0] = 1 instead of return 1 if amount == 0
  memo = Array.new(COINS.size){ Array.new(amount).tap{ |a| a[0] = 1 } }
  num_ways(amount, 0, memo)
end

def num_ways(amount, index, memo)
  return 0 if index >= COINS.size || amount < 0

  memo[index][amount] ||=
    num_ways(amount - COINS[index], index, memo) +
    num_ways(amount, index + 1, memo)
end
```

P.S. `dynamic-programming` tag is unnecessary :)

Comment: So creating a key of an array in a hash will auto generate multiple hash keys? My concern with using a 2D array is that it can be very wasteful and unnecessary for space

Comment: 1. `memo = {}; ... memo[ [amount, index] ] = num_ways(...` will produce huge amount of `Array` objects. It is bad if *speed* does matter. You can test it with Ruby's `benchmark`.

Comment: 2. 2D array (my example) is not *wasteful* in this *particular* case and I described *why*. You can inspect `memo` at the finish and find 0(**zero**) *unused* 2D array slots. So I claimed 2D array as best choice in this case.

Comment: @Sunny You can improve your algo skills at Leetcode. Here is me: https://leetcode.com/p1366/

Answer (score -1):

<s>Since identical arrays have different object ids, you couldn't just put the values as an array in a hash key. However</s> you can convert to string to make a simple lookup structure, for example converting to YAML/JSON

```
require 'json'

memo = {}
def memoize(*args, &blk)
  memo[args.to_json] ||= blk.call
end
def num_ways(amount, index)
  memoize(amount, index) do
    # original method body
  end
end
```

---

*edit*

nevermind, I guess I am wrong about the need to use `to_json`. You could just use `args` inside `memoize` and not `args.to_json`.

Comment: `a = [1,2]; h = {a=>7}; h[a] + h[a.dup] + h[[1,2]]`

Comment: also `.to_json` is not "free".

Comment: Using array as memoization key produces huge amount of Array instances. Not only for stored keys, but also every time when you read from memo. Its ok for very small data in usual app, but not in sport algo. BTW minus is not mine.